# Dynamic ReentrantReadWriteLock-s to synchronize access to large quantity of objects

Tags: java, multithreading, locking

My goal is to synchronize access to multiple (**thousands**) objects external to the program. `ReentrantReadWriteLock` provides a good model to control a **single** object. However, in my case it would be insane to create a RWL object for each of the object synchronized. Fortunately, less than **hundred** of them will be accessed at the same moment.

Thus, I decided to create a service which provides interface like this:

```
void acquireReadLock(String id) { 
   rwl = .......  // get or create RWL object
   rwl.writeLock().lock();
}

void acquireWriteLock(String id) {
}

void releaseReadLock(String id) {
}

void releaseWriteLock(String id) {
}
```

Implementation of "acquire" methods uses simple lazy initialization to instaniate RWL object for an item, or getting it from cache. However, "release" methods should include additional logic which checks if RWL is still needed (= has no locks). If not, I might safely remove the RWL from the cache, otherwise the memory would be flooded with them pretty soon.

To implement this cleanup logic I need a way to perfom the appropriate checks. Methods 'getReadLockCount()' and 'isWriteLocked()' seem to be suitable candidates, but this qoute from JavaDoc worries me alot:

> This method is designed for use in monitoring system state, not for
>   synchronization control.

So, is it safe to use them for my task? Is the any other solution possible?

Comment: Are you sure that creating thousands of `ReentrantReadWriteLock`s creates a problem? IMHO you should be able to create millions of them without negative impact on the JVM

Comment: Thousands is a typical quantity. In the long run the amount is basically unlimited - but RAM is not, even if JVM is able to handle them all at the same time.

Comment: What if I try to perform tryLock()? If succeed, it means no one has a lock of any type. Then I can safely remove the RWL from the list. I don't see any side effects at the moment.

Comment: `rwl.writeLock().tryLock()` is a bad idea because it will return true if it already acquired in the same thread

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use of getReadLockCount() and isWriteLocked() alone would not be safe for your task, since the lock might be free when the releasing thread called the functions, but another thread could acquire or start waiting on the lock before the releasing thread removed the lock from the cache.  The latter objection - that another thread could start waiting on the lock - applies to tryLock() as well.

One way of handling this would be to use a simple object as a guard lock, which would need to be synchronized on by any thread while locking or unlocking the read/write lock.  When a task completed, it would lock the guard lock, then if the read/write lock was entirely free, remove the read/write lock, then remove the guard lock.  There might be other threads waiting on the guard lock by then, but once they acquired it, they would see that there was no longer an available read/write lock, and they go back and create a new guard lock and read/write lock.

The process of creating the locks would need to be synchronized in some way - either globally using a `synchronized` block or functions, or perhaps using `ConcurrentHashMap` and its `putIfAbsent()` method - to avoid race conditions between two threads trying to create the locks at the same time.  The thread should have the guard lock locked before trying to put it and the new read/write lock into the cache, and if it got a different guard lock back from `putIfAbsent()`, abort the new lock creation and wait on the object returned instead.

Personally, because this approach is a bit complicated and could result in hidden race conditions if not written perfectly, I would consider just keeping just read/write locks around for all of the external objects.  There should be no problem with a million external objects at least, and tens or hundreds of millions if you have a few gigabytes of memory available for your process.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! I do was about to use sychronized block for accessing the cache, just have not mentioned it because it is quite obvious. As for race condition, I do not think this could have serious affect on the performance since the external objects are actually files with typical size of tens or even hundrends megabytes. Thus passing guard block is VERY unlikely would cause any thread to starve long enough. It is o(time) taking into accout data transfer.

Comment: What for cleaning the cache, I beleive I can make use of HashMap with weak values.